# Can I load a dropdownbox in MVC with no binding ? Getting 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'BLAH'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got two DropDownLists within an mvc 3 based site, 'teams' and 'users' :

```
Select a case worker : 
@Html.DropDownList("Teams", "-- Select A Team --") 
@Html.DropDownList("Users", "-- Select A User --")
```

I am populating teams using the following code which works OK :

```
    var teams = postroomEmplyees.GetPostRoomTeams();
    ViewData["Teams"] = new SelectList(teams, "UID", "Name");
```

I want to delay loading of any data into 'users' until a value in 'teams' has been selected by the user... HOWEVER... if I load the page without binding anything to 'users' I understanbly get

```
'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Blah'.'
```

In MVC can I have a dropdownlist load without binding to it.. and if so.. what the best way to achieve this ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a much more effiecent way.

```
ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<EmployeeOverview>(), "Uid", "FullName");
```

I can set the type to empty and then when the page loads it does't complain.  IT stops me doing any unneeded fake loads on start.

Answer (score 1):

With similar situations in the past I have created Users as an empty selectlist, and then used a JSON call on Teams SelectionChanged to populate the Users selectlist.

There's a rather more complex example and a plugin which could be used at this link:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/97/Cascading-DropDownLists-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET

Comment: I've create an empty list and bound to that, and I'm usiong JSON to do the update... it's the initial load that's stumping me as it still seems a bit of a messy hack.. but it has solved my prob.. thanks!